# Observables in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing few exercises to understand how Angularjs work... but I'm a bit confused at the moment...

Following the API, various documentation and tutorials I cannot find exactly what I would like to see...

So I created a small JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8HqnZ/

What I'm doing is really basic... and probably I'm also doing in a bad way... but I'm learning and every tips will be fantastic for me.

My target here is:

Make everything dynamic... obviously.

1. I don't understand why if I change name or date on my inputs on top my red bars do not update (seems like it isn't observable...)
2. I also created a get data button to see my updated Json but it return just `[object, Object]`...

In plus after I understand these two things I would like to make it inverse as well... I mean something like a draggable red bars that will update date on top... (if it is possible).

Here is my small app:

```
function App($scope) {
        $scope.windows = [
            {"name":"First Window","from":"2013-11-05","to":"2013-11-21"},
            {"name":"Second","from":"2013-11-10","to":"2013-11-30"},
            {"name":"Another One","from":"2013-11-17","to":"2013-11-20"}
        ];

        $scope.addWindow = function() {
            $scope.windows.push({"name":"insert name","from":"2013-11-01","to":"2013-11-02"});
        };

        $scope.setWindow = function(from, to) {
            var f = (from.split("-")[2]) * 40,
                t = ((to.split("-")[2]) * 40) - f;

            return { f: f, t: t };
        };



        $scope.getData = function() {
            console.log($scope.windows);
        };

    };
```

The HTML looks like this (I cutted off the "calendar"):

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="App">

    <section id="window-data">
        <div ng-repeat="window in windows">
            <label>Name:<input value="{{window.name}}"></label> <label>From:<input type="date" value="{{window.from}}"></label> <label>To:<input type="date" value="{{window.to}}"></label>
        </div>
        <button id="add-window" ng-click="addWindow()">Add Window</button>
    </section>

    <section id="window-display">
        <div id="date-labels">
            <div class="block">
                <span class="rotate">2013-11-01</span>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <span class="rotate">2013-11-02</span>
            </div>
            ...
        </div> 

        <div id="windows">
            <div class="window-container" ng-repeat="window in windows">
                <span class="window" style="left:{{setWindow(window.from, window.to).f}}px; width:{{setWindow(window.from, window.to).t}}px">{{window.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <button id="get-data" ng-click="getData()">Get Data</button>

</div>
```

Please if you know good websites with easy and deep documentation, examples, etc... share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always just used the Angular site for documentation. Have you [gone through their tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial)?

For your issues: You'll want to use `ng-model` on those inputs instead of setting the value.

```
<input ng-model="window.name">
```

The other issue occurred because you are trying to `console.log` JSON. You'll need to turn it into a string to log it:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.windows));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8HqnZ/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works on name change now! That's cool! But if I do the same on date values it doesn't work yet... Thanks for the console.log as well!

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo In my example I just did that one input. [updated fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/8HqnZ/3/) with `ng-model` applied to those others.

Comment: and what about the date? There is a way to make it observable as well?

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo yes, the exact same way. I included a link showing this in my previous comment.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo what do you mean "it doesn't work for date?"

Comment: If I change the date it do not update the red bar. And if I add `ng-model` on date input it doesn't work... just try!

Comment: Oh yes, you're right! I was still writing `{{window.from}}`. If you can help me to solve my last thing I will appreciate: Just which guide or how can I start to make now the red bars draggables and my input on top to change? Am I asking too much? Thanks for help.

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo not sure. Best bet is to try something, and when you have problems with code come back to SO for help!

Answer (score 0):

1.

> I don't understand why if I change name or date on my inputs on top
>   my red bars do not update (seems like it isn't observable...)

To do 2 way data binding you need to use ng-model 
Specifically you need to do this

```
`<input ng-model="window.name">`
```

instead of input value as "window.name"

> I also created a get data button to see my updated Json but it return
>   just [object, Object]...

This is as expected.

1. For a draggable, you need to create a custom angular js directive.